# Setting my custom property Name in XAML

Tags: wpf, designer

This is very narrow question and I am hesitant about posting it.

I'm defining some dummy data in the resources of my `Grid` in order to be able to see how my controls are rendered.

```
            <local:Team x:Key="DummyTeam">
            <local:Team.Members>
                <local:TeamMember Name="Edeax" Delay="3" />
                <local:TeamMember Name="Neled" Delay="3" />
            </local:Team.Members>
        </local:Team>
```

One funny bit is I want to define the property ´Name´ of ´TeamMember´ and since it is a commonly used attribute in XAML, Visual Studio complains with the following:

```
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.Metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode attribute.
```

It compiles and works fine, but, how to set `Name` property properly in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

Simply - convert to a nested argument, e.g.:

```
<local:TeamMember Delay="3" >
   <local:TeamMember.Name>Edeax</local:TeamMember.Name>
</local:TeamMember>
```